# Connecting to MySQL Database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I need help connecting to my MySQL Server on my web host. Here is the code for my Login button but it fails to log me in.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strConnect = "Server=localhost;Database=cpr_users;Uid=MyUsername;password=*******;";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect);
            MySqlCommand selectCmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from cpr_users.cpr_user_info where username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' ;", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();

            int count = 0;
            myReader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                this.Close();
                MedicalForm();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Theres 2 Users with that username Please contact Your_Name_Here ...Access Denied");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is Not correct .. Please try Again!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am unsure of whether I am using the wrong information for connection

When i use my webhost's dedicated IP and log in I am given the following error

```
Authentication to host '**IP ADDRESS**' for user 'MyUsername' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'MyUsername'@'myipaddress' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Specifically *how* does it fail?

Comment: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." @Steve

Comment: And your webhost is your localhost?

Comment: Is the connection string key really `password` or should it be `Pwd` instead?  Are you sure the credentials are valid for this host?

Comment: @Steve I am using GoDaddy to host the database

Comment: @David yes the credentials are correct, i am unsure of the "hostname" though

Comment: @TobyCook: Well, that's *probably* the problem then.  If you don't know the hostname of the database then you can't just randomly connect to it.  You kind of need to know what server the database is on.

Comment: @David I tried using the dedicated IP for my hosting but that too gave me an error

Comment: When you subscribed to their services they have given to you the information about the host name, the database name together with the password. You need to know these info to build your connectionstring. if you lost them then check with their support service. Not a programming problem

Comment: Plaintext passwords and string-concatenated sql parameters make me cry. This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the port number from the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `Server=localhost` by `Server=127.0.0.1` if it work verify your `hosts` file and set a correct redirection ... else verify with Mysql Prompt that the user & pass exists if it exist verify that it correctly written in you connection string